# Best way to get joint probability matrix from categorical data

Tags: numpy, matrix, parallel-processing, pytorch, tensor

My goal is to get joint probability (here we use count for example) matrix from data samples. Now I can get the expected result, but I'm wondering how to optimize it. Here is my implementation:

```py
def Fill2DCountTable(arraysList):
    '''
    :param arraysList: List of arrays, length=2
    each array is of shape (k, sampleSize),
        k == 1 (or None. numpy will align it) if it's single variable
        else k for a set of variables of size k
    :return: xyJointCounts, xMarginalCounts, yMarginalCounts
    '''
    jointUniques, jointCounts = np.unique(np.vstack(arraysList), axis=1, return_counts=True)
    _, xReverseIndexs = np.unique(jointUniques[[0]], axis=1, return_inverse=True) ###HIGHLIGHT###
    _, yReverseIndexs = np.unique(jointUniques[[1]], axis=1, return_inverse=True)
    xyJointCounts = np.zeros((xReverseIndexs.max() + 1, yReverseIndexs.max() + 1), dtype=np.int32)
    xyJointCounts[tuple(np.vstack([xReverseIndexs, yReverseIndexs]))] = jointCounts
    xMarginalCounts = np.sum(xyJointCounts, axis=1) ###HIGHLIGHT###
    yMarginalCounts = np.sum(xyJointCounts, axis=0)
    return xyJointCounts, xMarginalCounts, yMarginalCounts

def Fill3DCountTable(arraysList):
    # :param arraysList: List of arrays, length=3
    jointUniques, jointCounts = np.unique(np.vstack(arraysList), axis=1, return_counts=True)
    _, xReverseIndexs = np.unique(jointUniques[[0]], axis=1, return_inverse=True)
    _, yReverseIndexs = np.unique(jointUniques[[1]], axis=1, return_inverse=True)
    _, SReverseIndexs = np.unique(jointUniques[2:], axis=1, return_inverse=True)
    SxyJointCounts = np.zeros((SReverseIndexs.max() + 1, xReverseIndexs.max() + 1, yReverseIndexs.max() + 1), dtype=np.int32)
    SxyJointCounts[tuple(np.vstack([SReverseIndexs, xReverseIndexs, yReverseIndexs]))] = jointCounts
    SMarginalCounts = np.sum(SxyJointCounts, axis=(1, 2))
    SxJointCounts = np.sum(SxyJointCounts, axis=2)
    SyJointCounts = np.sum(SxyJointCounts, axis=1)
    return SxyJointCounts, SMarginalCounts, SxJointCounts, SyJointCounts
```

My use scenario is to do conditional independence test over variables. SampleSize is usually quite big (~10k) and each variable's categorical cardinality is relatively small (~10). I still find the speed not satisfying.

**How to best optimize this code, or even logic outside the code?** I may have some thoughts:

1. The `###HIGHLIGHT###` lines. On a single X I may calculate (X;Y1), (Y2;X), (X;Y3|S1)... for many times, so what if I save cache variable's (and conditional set's) {uniqueValue: reversedIndex} dictionary and its marginal count, and then directly get `marginalCounts` (no need to sum) and replace to get `reverseIndexs` (no need to unique).
2. How to further use matrix parallelization to do CITest in batch, i.e. calculate (X;Y|S1), (X;Y|S2), (X;Y|S3)... simultaneously?
3. Will `torch` be faster than `numpy`, on same CPU? Or on GPU?

**It's an open question. Thank you for any possible ideas. Big thanks for your help :)**

`================== A test example is as follows ==================`

```
xs = np.array(  [2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1]  )
ys = np.array(  [5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5]  )
Ss = np.array([ [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] ])

xyJointCounts, xMarginalCounts, yMarginalCounts = Fill2DCountTable([xs, ys])
SxyJointCounts, SMarginalCounts, SxJointCounts, SyJointCounts = Fill3DCountTable([xs, ys, Ss])
```

get 2D from (X;Y): `xMarginalCounts`=`[3 3 3 1]`, `yMarginalCounts`=`[5 4 1]`, and `xyJointCounts` (added axes name FYI):

```
xy| 4 5 6
--|-------
1 | 2 1 1
2 | 0 2 1
3 | 3 0 0
4 | 0 1 0
```

get 3D from (X;Y|{Z1,Z2}): `SxyJointCounts` is of shape `4x4x3`, where the first `4` means the cardinality of {Z1,Z2} (`00, 01, 10, 11` with respective `SMarginalCounts`=`[3 3 1 3]`). `SxJointCounts` is of shape `4x4` and `SyJointCounts` is of shape `4x3`.

Comment: FYI: I also implemented a C# version, with all ugly [for for for if if if] loop. Data stored in List, no array. However C# is still 10x faster than Python above :( How to beat C# by matrix parallelization?

Comment: I have yet another new idea. since `np.unique(axis=1)` is too slow, I can get rid of it by base operation. e.g. for 3 variables with respective cardinalities `a, b, c`, then a vector instance `[o, p, q]` can be translated to int `oa+pb+qc`.